# Typescript: how to set type as a key of interface

Tags: typescript, types, interface

Say I have an interface:

```
interface ExampleInterface {
  someItem: 'a' | 'b' | 'c'
  anotherItem: boolean
  lastItem: string
}
```

Say I want to set the type in another interface as `ExampleInterface.someItem` like:

```
 interface ExampleInterface2 {
  newItem: ExampleInterface.someItem
}
```

I don't want to create `type SomeItem = 'a' | 'b' | 'c'` and then set it in both. I'm trying to use an interface in an external typescript library.

is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I figure it out for anyone with the same issue:

```
interface ExampleInterface {
  someItem: 'a' | 'b' | 'c'
  anotherItem: boolean
  lastItem: string
}

interface ExampleInterface2 {
  newItem: ExampleInterface['someItem']
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yep, this is possible!

```
 interface ExampleInterface2 {
  newItem: ExampleInterface["someItem"]
}
```

Comment: You have basically copied the code the OP has shared, please add some context around this, how and why's.

Comment: In between me writing up a solution and posting it, the author posted their own solution.